# How to add "-" in the sting in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Input `str = "This is my string. We need to truncate this string to certain length"`

Output `str = "this-is-my-string-we-need"`

I tried this but need little bit efficient code : 
`str.split(" ").map{ |word| word + "-"}.join()`

Comment: Is this vanilla ruby, or in a rails project? I ask because there's an `ActiveSupport` method that might help: `String#dasherize`.

Comment: @TomLord String#dasherize will do this  dasherize('puni_puni') # => "puni-puni"

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-dasherize

Comment: Also, can you please clarify what logic you're aiming to achieve? How do you want to count characters -- before or after truncation? (E.g. Does the `"."` count as a character?) And if the truncation ends partway through a word, how should this be handled?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a friendly id i.e url for the blogs. Truncate the words

Comment: Oh.. and sorry, I meant [`String#parameterize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) not `dasherize`. You didn't answer my question, though: Is this a rails project, or vanilla ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your string will be proper text but perhaps it can have full stop (.), comma (,), question mark(?) and exlamation(!). As per your provided example in which you have ommitted full stop, I guess you are removing these special characters.

So here is little attempt to reach upto your scenario,

```
str = "This is my string. We need to truncate this string to certain length"
str.downcase.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z\s]/, '').gsub(/\s+/, '-')
# => "this-is-my-string-we-need-to-truncate-this-string-to-certain-length"
```